# Phalanger in production

Tags: php, compiler-construction, phalanger

Is Phalanger php compiler stable enough for production environment?
Does it need some extra server requirements (Web Host)? Can it be deployed using only .dll files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phalanger is used in [many commercial projects already](http://wiki.php-compiler.net/References). It is marked as beta only because it does not implement several PHP 5.4 functions yet.

It can be deployed standalone without a need of installing: [Installation-Free Phalanger web](http://www.php-compiler.net/?p=354)

To ensure your environment is optimized to work smoothly with Phalanger, I would recommend to take a look on [support page](http://www.php-compiler.net/support)

Comment: Can you please mention some site that use Phalanger?

Comment: e.g. sites built on http://www.jadu.co.uk/, http://www.php-compiler.net/, http://www.devsense.com/, http://wiki.php-compiler.net/, http://functional-programming.net/